Assign color to secondary axis title when using marrangeGrob
I am creating double axis plot using marrangeGrob and wondering if I can assign the color to the secondary axis title.
This is my code:
marrangeGrob(p1plot, nrow = 2, ncol = 2, right = yright, left = yleft)

Is their an equivalent statement to this in marrangeGrob?
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color = "black", size=15),
      axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "red", size=15))


It would be easier to help you if you provide a minimal reproducible example including a minimal but complete example code which others could run and a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.

From ?marrangeGrob : "right: optional string, or grob. e.g. right=grid::textGrob("title", rot=90, gp=grid::gpar(col="red")))
